# Skip payment method selection in Drupal Commerce

Tags: 7, commerce

I have just installed [Drupal Commerce](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce) Module with Paybox system and i wondering how can i bypass the "`payment method selection`". In fact there's only one payment method currently, so i'd like to bypass that step and proceed directly from the first step of the checkout to the last checkout step where there is the Paybox Js redirection.

Anyone already doing something similar?

Regards,
Geolim4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have to hide the payment method checkout pane via a form alteration, because the payment method still technically needs to be selected for the redirect page to show properly. However, if you just want to remove the "Review" page since you don't need it as an intermediate step for payment method selection, you could just move the payment method checkout pane to the "Checkout" page and disable the default review checkout pane.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean in the payment gateway, yes i tried, but the form seem to be block, i mean there's no way to go further as the form is blocked on the current page (checkout review).